# How to modify visited links separate from browser history?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I know that `a:visited` will modify it if the link is in the Browser history but how can I make for example a JavaScript that if in the past 5 days the link was not visited the "`<a>`" tag will not be seen as a visited site.

Comment: " <a> " tag 
Sorry I didn't see it is now shown.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for javascript to detect if a link is visited. 
That is because Browsers take security and privacy seriously. 
From the CSS2 specifications:

> It is possible for style sheet authors to abuse the :link and :visited
>   pseudo-classes to determine which sites a user has visited without the
>   user's consent.
>
> UAs may therefore treat all links as unvisited links, or implement
>   other measures to preserve the user's privacy while rendering visited
>   and unvisited links differently.

See this [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector) for more Information

Comment: I see. But is there any way to for example store visited status for user for X amount of time after that reset. So for exapmle if the site was not visited in the past 5 days it will be normal.

Comment: If the links are on the same domain as your site you could achieve that via Javascript by storing all the visited pages with a timestamp to the localStorage of the Browser. On document load you could than add classes and style them instead of the :visited pseudo element.

Comment: I did a bit of thinking and my best idea is this: Lets give the link an id like ```id="link_no1"``` and if the user clicks on it the id will change to ```id="clicked"``` and format that with CSS.